# Locally map or redirecting an URL to another URL for the client side?

Tags: dns, ip-address, hosts-file

Is it possible to redirect an URL to another URL, for the client only. As example.

Let's say, I type this in the URL browser https://google.com/this_page_does_not_exist/it_doesnt_exist

it just gives me a 404 page

Is it possible to override this for the client locally itself, as in like DNS or something? So that if I would try to look up https://google.com/this_page_does_not_exist/it_doesnt_exist that I could modify and tell it to bring me to a different address?

So, instead of letting the server handle the redirect, override it and let the client control that part completly.

Something like hosts file, but instead, it matches the URL and if it matches make it go to the set value.

Example:
`https://google.com/this_page_does_not_exist/it_doesnt_exist https://google.com`

So that whenever this "https://google.com/this_page_does_not_exist/it_doesnt_exist" gets looked up for the client that set it, it would just bring them to https://google.com

Comment: May be this could be done using a browser plugin developer for that purpose or a Man-in-the-middle proxy but the latter isn't really a good solution for every day use.

Comment: I'm not aiming for browser, I'm aiming for application API calls as well

Comment: Then the only possibility would be an URL rewriting script inside a intercepting Proxy like mitmproxy, Fiddler [Classic], Burp..., that is used by all programs. Because of HTTPS the communication the path is protected by HTTPS, and as the path only exists inside the HTTPS connection you have to break up the connection to be able to modify it.